# How to handle connectivity issues?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am currently working on an app which uses Azure Mobile Services. Everything works fine until the app loose network or Internet connectivity. At that point, exceptions are thrown and the app crashes.

I can easily fix the situation by wrapping all my calls to Azure Mobile Services inside try..catch blocks, but is this the best way to deal with this kind of situations?

My question is the following: What are the best practices to handle property network related errors? Is there an appropriate design pattern to handle this? Is wrapping the calls in try..catch blocks fine?

P.S. In this situation I don't worry about retry logic.

Answer (score 0):

Martin,

What kind of app are you building? Most platforms have APIs that will allow you to listen in on network changes & internet connectivity before you try making remote calls. The Try-Catch blocks should be used to trap exception conditions when something unexpected fails.

If building a Windows Store app, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2013/04/01/detectingnetwork-connection-in-windows-store-apps.aspx.

For Windows Phone apps, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487166(v=vs.105).aspx

Hope this helps!